# Hibernate Named Query (HQL) search with keyword

Tags: hibernate, hql

I would like to create a query where able to search person name based on wild-card search of person fullname or person username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually quite confused. You say you entity class is named PersonEntity.java and yet your HQL query selects from Operson.

In HQL, you query against a Java object not an actual table. Anyway, I will assume that your Entity is named Operson. Here's the correct code:

```
public List<Operson> searchPerson(String keyword) {
    try {
        String HQL = "SELECT o FROM Operson o WHERE o.opusername like :username OR o.opname like :name";
        return em.createQuery(HQL)
          .setParameter("username", "%" + keyword.toUpperCase() + "%")
          .setParameter("name", "%" + keyword.toUpperCase() + "%")
          .getResultList();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note:

1. When using parameters, you don't include the wildcard characters in your HQL query. You use the wildcard characters when you are setting the actual parameters via setParameter().
2. Your method should return List

Comment: hi, ,i have put in the wrong name it should be OPerson.java instead of PersonEntity.java. I have make the changes. What if i want to have query: public List<Operson> searchPerson(String keyword) {  }. how should i gonna do it?

Comment: You have 2 parameters in your query so I thought you should be needing 2 parameters in your method as well. What specifically do you want to do with the keyword parameter? Will the same keyword be passed to username and user parameters in your query?

Comment: yes. the keyword use to passed to username and user parameter in my query. that is the things that i confuse about. i know that when passed 2 parameters then i should put 2 parameter in my method. What if i use keyword to pass 2 parameters (username and name)?

Comment: simple, set the 2 query parameters with the same keyword variable. I updated the code to reflect that

Comment: okay. Now i know the concept about it. really thanks for the helps :D